# Select2 strips all attributes from <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sonata-admin, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 on my `select` tag, There is some additional when the user changes the selected option. and it makes use of attributes that I set as `data-price` for instance. Select2 seems to be striping all attributes from the `<option>` tags except for the `value`.

How can I disable this behavior or how can I get the data values some other way?

Edit: I forgot to add that I'm also using Sonata admin. Sonata is the one loading select2 by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out select2 was set to use remote data so my `option` elements were being replaced. I set my data attributes in the AJAX callback function and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

> Select2 seems to be striping all attributes from the  tags except for the value

Not really true the `data-*` attributes still there you have just to get them :

```
$("#singleSelectExample").select2();

$('body').on('change', '#singleSelectExample', function(){
    console.log( $('#singleSelectExample option:selected').data('price') );
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#singleSelectExample").select2();

$('body').on('change', '#singleSelectExample', function(){
  console.log( $('#singleSelectExample option:selected').data('price') );
})
```

```css
.selectRow {
  display : block;
  padding : 20px;
}
.select2-container {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.5.1/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="selectRow">
  <select id="singleSelectExample">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1" data-price="111">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="222">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="333">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, the data attributes are preserved in the HTML. That doesn't happen in my case. Maybe something else is the cause and not select2, but your example works fine while mine doesn't.